# How to optimize SQL query generated by Entity Framework in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I create a query in linq which returns a table of most active salesmen in my shop:

```
ProjectDB3Context db = new ProjectDB3Context();

db.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
var result = db.tblUsers.Join(db.tblSales,
                              u => u.ID,
                              sl => sl.tblUserId,
                              (u, sl) => new { u, sl })
               .Select(o => new
                            {
                                UserId = o.u.ID,
                                Login = o.u.UserLogin,
                                FullName = o.u.Name + " " +  o.u.Surname,
                                ItemsToSell = db.tblSales.Where(x => x.tblUserId == o.u.ID).Count()
                            })
               .Distinct()
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemsToSell)
               .ToList();
```

The henerated SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Distinct1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Distinct1].[UserLogin] AS [UserLogin], 
    [Distinct1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Distinct1].[C3] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Project1].[UserLogin] AS [UserLogin], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Project1].[Name] + N' ' + [Project1].[Surname] AS [C2], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
            [Extent1].[UserLogin] AS [UserLogin], 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[tblSale] AS [Extent3]
                WHERE [Extent3].[tblUserId] = [Extent1].[ID]) AS [C1]
            FROM  [dbo].[tblUser] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblSale] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[tblUserId]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Distinct1]
    ORDER BY [Distinct1].[C3] DESC
```

Statistics:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 359 ms,  elapsed time = 529 ms.
```

[Execution plan screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIQRM.png)

I want to optimize the generated SQL query and insert optimized query into a stored procedure. SQL Server Management Studio gives me a tip to create a nonclustered index (tblUserId) on tblSale (you can see this tip in image that I included).

When I create it using command:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ProductVendor_tblUserId 
ON tblSale (tblUserId);
```

and then run the SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio I get:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 328 ms,  elapsed time = 631 ms.
```

So it takes much longer after I used index to optimize my SQL query.

Can anybody help me with optimize this query in SQL Server using indexes?

Comment: It doesn't take *much longer* after the index is created - CPU time is actually **down** .... have you looked at the **actual execution plans** for the query *before* creating the index, and after? See what's changed - it might show you additional tips on how to further improve your query

Comment: Something is wrong with your query. Start with why joining the two tables (which multiplicates the records in `tblUsers`) and then not using the second table record in the projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anybody help me with optimize this query in SQL Server using indexes?

First off, before trying to optimize the SQL query in database, make sure your LINQ query is optimal. Which is not the case with yours. There is unnecessary join which in turn requires distinct etc. And `tblSales` is accessed twice (see the generated SQL).

What you are trying to achieve is to get users with sales ordered by sales count descending. The following simple query should produce the desired result

```
var result = db.tblUsers
   .Select(u => new
   {
       UserId = u.ID,
       Login = u.UserLogin,
       FullName = u.Name + " " +  u.Surname,
       ItemsToSell = db.tblSales.Count(s => s.tblUserId == u.ID)
    })
    .Where(x => x.ItemsToSel > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemsToSell)
    .ToList();
```

Try and see the new execution plan/time.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to optimize the generated SQL query and insert optimized query into a stored procedure.

Bzzt. Wrong.

Your query is already "optimized" - in that there isn't anything you can do to the query itself to improve its runtime performance.

Stored procedures in SQL Server **do not** have any kind of magic-optimization or other real advantages over immediately-executed queries. Stored procedures do benefit from cached execution plans, but so do immediate-queries after their first execution, and execution-plan generation isn't that expensive an operation.

Anyway, using stored procedures for read-only `SELECT` operations is inadvisble, it is better to use an UDF (`CREATE FUNCTION`) so you can take advantage of function composition which can be optimized and runtime far better than nested stored procedure calls.

If SQL Server's Show Execution Plan feature tells you to create an index, that is outside of EF's responsibility, it is also outside a stored procedure's responsibility too. Just define the index in your database and include it in your setup script. Your EF-generated query will run much faster without it being a stored procedure.